# two Density Heatmaps in two horizontal subplots

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly, heatmap, plotly-python

I can plot a column of my DataFrame using [2D Histograms or Density Heatmaps](https://plotly.com/python/2D-Histogram/).

```
flights = pd.read_csv('Flights dataset.csv')

fig = px.density_heatmap(flights_dest, x='DEST_CITY_NAME', marginal_x="histogram")
fig.show()
```

I want to Plot two columns from two different DataFrames using Density Heatmaps in a figure that contains two horizontal subplots.

From [Subplots in Python](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/), I see that I should use `plotly.graph_objects` library to implement subplots:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]),
    row=1, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[20, 30, 40], y=[50, 60, 70]),
    row=1, col=2
)

fig.update_layout(height=600, width=800, title_text="Side By Side Subplots")
fig.show()
```

But I cannot find the equivalent of [Density Heatmaps](https://plotly.com/python/2D-Histogram/) which are created using `plotly.express` in  `plotly.graph_objects` library.

Any idea how to implement it?

Comment: I don't understand if 2D Histogram and Density Heatmaps are the same, but I was able to draw the graph with different data by specifying go.Histgram2d() in the subplot. The color bars need to be controlled.

Comment: @r-beginners in `density_heatmap` I can add `marginal_x="histogram"`. But, in `Histgram2d()`, it doesnt support that.

Comment: how important is histogram as well as heatmap?  I can find a solution for just heatmap

Comment: @RobRaymond its not a MUST but I prefer to have that as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach.

- Create the figures you want from data frames using **Plotly Express**
- integrate them into *sub-plots* by adding traces created in previous step
- fix up layout. *Histograms* invisible, *heatmaps* colorbar per trace

Alternatives attempted:

- integrate data frames `pd.concat()` then use **Plotly Express** with `row_facet`.  This does not produce any histograms, just heatmap

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = px.data.tips()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"total": np.random.uniform(15, 25, 100), "var": np.random.uniform(1, 5, 100)}
)
fig = make_subplots(rows=4, cols=1)

# build plots to be integrated into sub-plots
figs = [
    px.density_heatmap(df2, x="total", y="var", marginal_x="histogram"),
    px.density_heatmap(df, x="total_bill", y="tip", marginal_x="histogram"),
]

# integrated into sub-plots
for fn, f in enumerate(figs):
    for tn, t in enumerate(f.data[::-1]):
        if fn>0 and isinstance(t, go.Histogram2d):
            t = t.update(coloraxis=f"coloraxis{tn+1}")
        fig.add_trace(t, row=(fn * 2) + (tn + 1), col=1)

fig.update_layout(xaxis_visible=False, xaxis3_visible=False)
fig.update_layout(height=500, coloraxis_colorbar_x=.95)
fig.update_xaxes(domain=[0,.94])
```